# Office Script - If statement with array inside For loop not working

Tags: javascript, excel, typescript, office-scripts

I have tried to make an Office Script that loops through each row and finds the one with the text "Total" in column A and then deletes that row.
I have not managed to make it work, does anyone know how to change it?

```js
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {

  //getting the used range in the worksheet
  let usedRange = workbook.getActiveWorksheet().getUsedRange();

  //getting the row count of the used range
  let lastRow = usedRange.getRowCount();

  usedRange = workbook.getActiveWorksheet().getRangeByIndexes(0, 0, (usedRange.getRowIndex() + lastRow), 19)

  //getting the values of the range
  let values = usedRange.getValues();

  //getting the row count of the range
  let rowCount = usedRange.getRowCount();

  //for every row starting at the last row, checking if the cell in column 'A' contains text "Total". If it is, then delete the entire row. 
  for (let i = rowCount - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (values[i][18] == "Total") {
      usedRange.getCell(i, 1).getEntireRow().delete(ExcelScript.DeleteShiftDirection.up)
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: Please show your script and all relevant code (a minimal reproducible example - https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) here so we know better what we're dealing with.

Comment: `@user1599011 I have uploaded my code but it does not include the deletion of the row that includes "Total" in column A.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It should be clear what I am asking. I want to delete the row of the first cell that has the text "Total" in column A.

Comment: Your code makes no reference to "Total"; please include your attempt achieve this objective.

Comment: I can not include it since I do not know how to write it, I was hoping someone else would know how to tackle the problem.

Comment: @Rosenz5 - `I was hoping someone else would know how to tackle the problem` that's not what we're here for, we'll help you work through problems in existing code you have that you can't find a fix for, we won't use our free time writing code for someone else, that's a job and people deserve to be paid for that

Comment: @user1599011, I have edited the original question with the right code now that I have tried to create. What am I doing wrong in the code? Thank you in advance.

Comment: @CanO'Spam I have edited the original question with the right code now that I have tried to create. What am I doing wrong in the code? Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the outcome when you run your code as-is? How does that differ from your expected outcome?

Comment: I think you want to post your question in the Office-Scripts board. I'd post your answer there or add it in the tags. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/office-scripts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is on this line:

```
if (values[i][18] == "Total") {
```

The first array `[i]` takes the argument which corresponds to the row in the Excel worksheet. The second array `[18]` takes the argument which corresponds to the column in the Excel worksheet. Since arrays are zero based, the first column, Column A, would correspond to index zero. So you just have to update the value from 18 to 0. And it should perform this check on column A. So the updated code will look like this:

```
  if (values[i][0] == "Total") {
```